# in one ear and out the other

Tags: grammaticality

> His lecture went in my one ear and out my other ear.

If I use the determiner ***my***, would it be grammatical to omit the headword ear in the second phrase of the conjunction, like this:

> . . . in my one ear and out my other.

Comment: **in one ear and out the other** is an idiom.

Comment: It wouldn't match the normal idiom, but, to answer your question, I find nothing "ungrammatical" about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is "in one ear and out the other" and it is used without possessive determiners. (The following examples have been taken from the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*.)

> So hearing all those things, I pretty much let it go **in one ear and out the other**.

> First day on the job, names went **in one ear and out the other**.

> And when they tease you, it doesn't just go **in one ear and out the other**.

> I promise you, I hear it, and **it goes in one ear and out the other**.

If you were to use the possessive determiners, you should say "in one of my ears and out of my other ear," but that is not the idiomatic expression. It is probable you would be understood the same, though.